# SQL "Count (Distinct...)" returns 1 less than actual data shows?

Tags: sql, count, distinct

I have some data that doesn't appear to be counting correctly.  When I look at the raw data I see 5 distinct values in a given column, but when I run an "Count (Distinct ColA)" it reports 4.  This is true for all of the categories I am grouping by, too, not just one.  E.g. a 2nd value in the column reports 2 when there are 3, a 3rd value reports 1 when there are 2, etc.

Table A:  ID, Type

Table B:  ID_FK, WorkID, Date

Here is my query that summarizes:

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT B.ID_FK), A.Type
FROM A INNER JOIN B ON B.ID_FK = A.ID
WHERE Date > 5/1/2013 and Date < 5/2/2013
GROUP BY Type
ORDER BY Type
```

And a snippet of the results:

```
4|Business
2|Design
2|Developer
```

Here is a sample of my data, non-summarized.  Pipe is the separator; I just removed the 'COUNT...' and 'GROUP BY...' parts of the query above to get this:

```
4507|Business
4515|Business
7882|Business
7889|Business
7889|Business
8004|Business
4761|Design
5594|Design
5594|Design
5594|Design
7736|Design
7736|Design
7736|Design
3132|Developer
3132|Developer
3132|Developer
4826|Developer
5403|Developer
```

As you can see from the data, Business should be 5, not 4, etc.  At least that is what my eyes tell me.  :)

I am running this inside a FileMaker 12 solution using it's internal ExecuteSQL call.  Don't be concerned by that too much, though: the code should be the same as nearly anything else.  :)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
J

Comment: Just to rule out the obvious... you're also including your `where` clause in that non-aggregated data set... correct?

Comment: I would be tempted to try removing the `distinct` and using a `group by` on the two columns instead eg `group by Type, B.ID_FK`, just to see if there are any differences.

Comment: Does this product translate `Date > 5/1/2013` as you expect? I think you should make those `Date > '5/1/2013'` or even better `Date > '2013-01-05'`.

Comment: Could you give a data of Date columns, please?

Comment: @Michael:  Yes, the WHERE clause was included in the non-aggregated query.    AT-Rots:  I will give that a try and see how it goes.  AT-Ypercube and Alex:  Yes, it should be translating as I expect.  I am getting the raw data returned that I am expecting.  This is a bit where doing this in FileMaker comes into play:  I am using a placeholder/variable-substitution to pull the date in from another field in the DB.  The SQL I posted was manually cleaned up to make it more generic, so I hand type those dates.  But they do work and they are the same in both queries.

Comment: @Rots:  Interesting.  Here is what I got when I removed the 'DISTINCT' word (leaving the COUNT()), and added a GROUP BY for the second field:   [ Business,   1
Business,   1
Business,   1
Business,   11
Business,   1
Design,   1
Design,   21
Design,   5
Developer,   8
Developer,   1
Developer,   1].     
    So, if you count those results, you DO get the correct numbers of Types (5, 3, 3).

Comment: @Cronk that is interesting, so as a final approach if the solutions given don't work you could resort to using groups. Not a bad thing.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), Type
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT B.ID_FK, A.Type Type
      FROM A
      INNER JOIN B ON B.ID_FK = A.ID
      WHERE Date > 5/1/2013 and Date < 5/2/2013) x
GROUP BY Type
ORDER BY Type
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be a FileMaker issue, have you seen [this post](http://forums.filemaker.com/posts/d981c59865) on the FileMaker forum?  It describes the same issue (a count distinct smaller by 1) with 11V3 back in 03/2012 with a plug in, then [updated](http://forums.filemaker.com/posts/4d4bb0da3e) with same issue with 12v3 in 11/2012 with ExecuteSQL.  It didn't seem to be resolved in either case.

Other considerations might be if there are any referential integrity constraints on the joined tables, or if you can get a query execution plan, you might find it is executing the query differently than expected.  not sure if FileMaker can do this.

I like Barmar's suggestion, it would sort twice.

If you are dealing with a bug, directing the COUNT DISTINCT, Join and/or Group By by structuring the query to make them happen at different times might work around it:

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT x.ID), x.Type
FROM (SELECT A.ID ID, A.Type Type
        FROM A
       INNER JOIN B ON B.ID_FK = A.ID
       WHERE B.Date > 5/1/2013 and B.Date < 5/2/2013) x
GROUP BY Type
ORDER BY Type
```

you might also try replacing B.ID_FK with A.ID, who knows what context it applies, such as:
   SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT A.ID), A.Type

Comment: No, I hadn't seen that post.  I will go investigate that, and your other comments also.  Thanks for replying!